# how to disable Eclipse CDT Tool's option?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

In our RCP we have an option under Tool. We want to disable this option programatically.

When I checked if there is a code for option enabled, I see there in not. Only Tool has is enabled and no set Enabled.

We want to disable the option (C[image]an be seen but not pressed.)?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "option under Tool".  Are you talking about a menu item? Context menu item? Toolbar button? Preference page?

Comment: I added a picture we want to disable the IOption at the right page.

Answer (score 0):

Under your tool locate your option in org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.buildDefinitions extensions under the plugin.xml...

There in option there is applicabilityCalculator. There generate a class that implements IOptionApplicability...

Fill the 3 methods.

Please ask for more information if you didnt get it.